# PHP - methods of a object

Tags: php, oop, magento, magento-1.7

I'm a Java developer trying to understand this PHP behavior. I've executed the following methods:

```
error_log(get_class($a) . "\n", 3, "c:\my-errors.log");
error_log(print_r(get_class_methods($a), true) . "\n", 3, "c:\my-errors.log");
```

which printed

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
Array
(
    [0] => getStoreId
    ...
    [90] => getWeight
    [91] => getOptionInstance
    [92] => getProductOptionsCollection
    [93] => addOption
    [94] => getOptionById
    [95] => getOptions
    [96] => getIsVirtual
    ...
    [182] => flagDirty
)
```

But the next line executes (without errors) a method which is clearly not in the list of methods I printed first:

```
$a->getOption()
```

So, how is it possible? How can I know all the methods an object have? Is there any way of knowing which file will execute the "next line of code" - since there are several "getOption" functions all over the project and I cant figure it out which one is going to be executed.

Maybe this can help you, I'm working with Magento 1.7 and the code I'm talking about is at

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Bundle\Model\Product\Type.php@shakeSelections
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP information you want to look into is the [`__call` magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).  The short version — if you call an non-existant method on a PHP object, the `__call` method is invoked, giving PHP developers the opportunity to implement meta-programming features.

The Magento feature you're interested in are magic setters and getters.  Magento objects that inherit from `Varien_Object` (usually models and blocks) have magic `get` and `set` methods, implemented with the aforementioned `__call` method.

You can grab an array of data in an object with

```
$array = $object->getData();
```

That array might look like

```
array(
  'foo'           =>'bar',
  'another_field' =>'baz'
)
```

You can also access the values of the `foo` and `another_field` with calls to the aforementioned magic getters

```
echo $this->getFoo();
echo $this->getAnotherField();
```

You could also set new values with the magic `setter`

```
$this->setFoo('no longer bar');
$this->setAnotherField('no longer baz');
```

The setters are also chain-able.

```
$this->setFoo('again!')->setAnotherField('back to baz');
```

If a data property is not set, the getter will return `null`.  That mean anytime you see a call to

```
$object->get...
$object->set...
```

the return **may** be coming from a real method, or may be coming from a magic data setter and getter.